# Add all images in subfolders to PDF document in iTextSharp as new pages?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have a folder structure like this below:

```
D:\myphotos\2011-02-09\1.jpg
D:\myphotos\2011-02-10\2.jpg
....
......
............
D:\myphotos\2011-02-23\10.jpg
```

I need to add all these images as new pages to a pdf document using iTextSharp. How can 
I achieve this minimally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the basic idea. You might have to resize the images. If so, just resize the image like you normally would in .Net, save the image to a MemoryStream and create the `Jpeg` object from the raw bytes.

```
//Create a new document
iTextSharp.text.Document Doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 20, 20, 20, 20);
//Store the document on the desktop
string PDFOutput = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Output.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream(PDFOutput, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));

//Open the PDF for writing
Doc.Open();

string Folder = "C:\\Images";
foreach (string F in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.jpg")) {
    //Insert a page
    Doc.NewPage();
    //Add image
    Doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Jpeg(new Uri(new FileInfo(F).FullName)));
}

//Close the PDF
Doc.Close();
```

Comment: string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\My Sample Path\","*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories); to get all sub directories.